# How to execute bash script in same shell

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which is calling three different commands and that execution must happen in one shell. I got it by adding && after each command like as follows-

```
CMD1 && CMD2 && CMD3
```

Now what i need is- lets say i open a terminal on my MAC machine, all commands should run in open shell not in new sub-shell.

As a side note- CMD1 is actually a source command to my project directory which is a bash script which sets all the environment variable for running server.

Comment: You're looking for `source` or `.`: `$> . myscript`

Comment: thanks @KyleStrand actually my CMD1 is itself a source command. That is why i am looking for running bash script in current shell. Because CMD2 and CMD3 depends on environment set by CMD1.

Comment: ...then your question is unclear; commands aren't intrinsically "source commands". Do you mean that your script actually looks like `. CMD1 && CMD2 && CMD3`? If so, your question should say that.

Comment: The environment is inherited by subshells.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what your script looks like and what your requirements are. "CMD2 and CMD3 depends on environment set by CMD1" should be specified in the *question itself*, not in a comment.

Comment: It's also unclear what you mean by "execution must be in sequence". Bash execution is *always* in-sequence, except when you start a new Bash shell as a background process (which is not likely to be something you'd do accidentally). `&&` has the additional property of *halting* execution of commands as soon as one of them has a non-zero return value.

Comment: @KyleStrand Edited the question. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, you will need to save save the command in a scriptfile, for example `Myscript.sh`.

Second, you can execute the script file to run your commands simultaneously using

```
. ./Myscript.sh
```

The first `.` stands for current shell and the second `.` for current directory.

Comment: Would be nice to explain also that it's actually sourcing the bash script

Comment: What is the difference between running a script with source and the answer mentioned above ?