# How to write script for initializing sdkman versions in a shell

Tags: linux, macos, sdkman

I am using *SDKMAN!* and I am trying to write `sdkinit.sh` script for my project to initialize current shell with specific tools versions.

```sh
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk use groovy 2.4.16
sdk use java 8.0.212-zulu
```

Even though I call the script, the changes are not applied to shell according to the following output

```sh
➜  dir git: ✗ ./sdkinit.sh

-e Using groovy version 2.4.16 in this shell.

-e Using java version 8.0.212-zulu in this shell.

➜  dir ✗ java -version
openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu12.2+3-CA (build 12.0.1+12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu12.2+3-CA (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I use *zsh* on *macOS*.

Is there a way to make it working?

I see there's [issue](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/683) for it in the project, but it's not started yet, so I am looking for writing my own script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script is running in separate bash. You can try executing script like that.

`. ./sdkinit.sh`

For more information look here:
[How to execute bash script in same shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122714/how-to-execute-bash-script-in-same-shell)