# Why a MAC OS X 'terminal command' run by a Python script gives error output "command not found"?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal, sdkman

**Environment:**

Python 3.8

Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.6

**Problem:**

When I open my terminal in my macbook and I run this command:

```
user$sdk version
```

I get no issue and I can see version number of sdkman:

```
SDKMAN 5.9.0+555
```

But if I try to do the same from my Python 3.8 script, I get an error output:

```
command_sdkman_version_0='sdk version'
os.system(command_sdkman_version_0)


sh: sdk: command not found
```

When I print the PATH environment variable from terminal and from the script, they are both the same.

When I use 'sudo sdk version', I have same issue.

What is wrong?

Comment: Try using the full path to `sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but using a shell script.
For me the fix was that when running the script instead of using
./scriptName.sh
i had to use
. ./scriptName.sh

For a more detailed explication please see the fallowing post:
[How to execute bash script in same shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122714/how-to-execute-bash-script-in-same-shell)